# Can you assign objects to Session in the ASP.NET C# Page_Unload method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am creating an ASP.NET application (using C# as the server scripting language), and need to use Session to retain data between postbacks. I am using an UpdatePanel and will have lists of textboxes etc. which are changed on the fly. These lists will be global to the code behind class. When the page posts back I will need to save the changes to these lists (and other global class variables) and so will need to save them to session. I know that lists are stored in memory and so don't actually need to be stored in session, but please ignore this fact; I am just testing the idea :P. Can it be done, and is it good programming practice if it can, to write everything to Session in the `Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)` method of the code behind?

Comment: If  the list is dynamic(i.e. you have added controls/content at run time) and if you do not store it in the session, there is no way to retain the state of the list. If will be lost during postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) -

> The Unload event is raised after the page has been fully rendered,
>   sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded.

As such I can see no good reason for you to be using it to store values in the Session. A more appropriate place to save the session is in the event that handles the changes to the controls in question (i.e. the text boxes you refer to).

This also keeps your code methods more focused on their responsibilities. For example if you want to save the value of a particular text box in the `OnChange` event, save it's value to the session in that event. Another option is of course to perform all of this in a Button Click (e.g. Save) event on post back.